# Failed to convert 'x$date' to class “Date” in R

Tags: r, date

Okay so I have been trying to use this package from Facebook, but for some reason I keep seeing this error.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(quantmod)
library(prophet)
library(dplyr)

SPY <-tq_get(get = "stock.prices", "SPY", from = "2016-01-01")

df<-select(SPY,c(date,close))
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date),format="%Y-%m-%d")
colnames(df)<-c("ds","y")
m<-prophet(df)
future<-make_future_dataframe(m,periods=52, freq = "d")
forecast <- predict(m,future)
plot(m,forecast)
```

When I run the plot function, I would see this error message:

> Error in as.Date.default(x$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y") :  do not know how to convert 'x$date' to class “Date”

I tried using as.Date function, strptime function, and format function but it was in no use.

```
forecast$ds<-as.Date(paste(forecast$ds),"%Y-%m-%d")
forecast$ds<- format(forecast$ds, "%d/%m/%Y")
forecast$date<-forecast$ds
m$date<-forecast$ds
```

This didn't work

```
df$newdate<- strptime(as.character(df$ds),"%Y-%m-%d")
df$newdate<- format(df$newdate, "%d/%m/%Y")
df$newdate<-as.Date(df$newdate)
dp<-data.frame(df$newdate,y)
```

and this didn't work either. They were some answers provided by other similar postings but I do not really see what is causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give a try on `lubridate` package it has lot function that you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

The error message is caused by some quirks of `as.Date()`. The workaround is to save the dataset as a CSV file using `write.csv()` and then read in again as a CSV using `read.csv()`. And then use `as.Date()`. This will eliminate the error message.

Another workaround is to use `as.data.frame()` first for your entire dataset before using `as.Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <- ymd(df$date) # ymd stands for year, month, date
```

or

```
library(anydate)
df$date <- anydate(df$date)
```

Plotting works afterwards for me.

Comment: library(anydate): the anydate package is not on CRAN.

Comment: sorry, it should be library(anytime)